# I find myself using "if self != nil" a lot because of [weak self] ...is this normal?

Tags: swift

Example (in my view controller):

```
RESTApi.fetchUser() { [weak self] Void in 
    if self != nil { //the view controller is still here.
        self!.items.append(stuff)
        self!.whatever

    }
}
```

I notice that I'm using `if self != nil` immediately, followed by `self!` everywhere. Is there a better way? I feel like this is against the Swift way.

Note: I use [weak self] because my ViewController could be nil (if the user goes back before the REST Api downloads the data).

Comment: Doesn't self get captured anyway so that is doesn't matter if the user goes back before the REST API is completed?

Comment: I'm not sure. I always use [weak self] when it comes to ViewControllers.  Can anyone else comment on this?

Comment: It does seem to be a common pattern. I think if you don't make it weak,  the captured self can introduce a reference cycle and mess up memory management.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you use `if let`?

```
if let unwrappedSelf = self {
    unwrappedSelf.items.append(stuff)
    ...
}
```

You could also use `guard let`:

```
guard let unwrappedSelf = self else { return }

unwrappedSelf.items.append(stuff)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is cool.  Is there any difference between my way and yours?

Comment: `if let` is more idiomatic. Gets rid of the `!`. You could also do `guard let else return`

Comment: @TIMEX Thilo is correct. I'll add the `guard` to my answer.

Comment: `weakSelf` isn't a good name because if it is a strong reference.

Answer (score 6):

Idle you have to use `guard` which is more idle then the `if`

```
guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

strongSelf.items.append(stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just calling methods on `self` when the closure is invoked, then you don't even need to use `if let`, `guard let`, or `if self != nil`.  The below code also works just fine to call the methods if `self` is not nil, and to do nothing if it is:

```
RESTApi.fetchUser() { [weak self] in 
    self?.items.append(stuff)
    self?.whatever()
}
```

This conditional unwrapping is usable in all cases except those where you need to pass `self` or a property of `self` as an argument to a non-optional function parameter, or assign `self` or a property of `self` to a variable with a non-optional type.

As a broader note, there isn't necessarily a need to make `self` weak in this scenario anyway. That's usually only needed if `self` is retaining the closure that references `self` inside as an ivar (circular reference).  In your case, it's `RestApi` that's holding a reference to the closure, and the view controller that `self` is referring to would be retained by the closure until the closure returned. At that point, if the view controller had already been dismissed by the user and the closure's reference was the last reference to it, it would then be deallocated after the closure executed (no circular reference).

So making `self` weak in this example only applies if you specifically want the scenario of dismissing the view controller to deallocate the instance and the closure to then fail to run anything at all.

Comment: Fair point, but weak reference is still meaningful when the view controller is nil there is no point in processing the fetched result. (assuming the fetched result is only used for displaying in the view controller)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
   guard let `self` = self else {
       return
   }
   self.items.append(stuff)
```